# Server is not visible from internet

Tags: networking, internet

I've set up a server running 12.04 server edition which is connected to internet via LTE modem and shared to the internet as a WiFi hotspot. I've also installed no-ip on a server and gave it a host.

So when I try to SSH to server using its local IP (10.10.0.1), everything is OK. But when I try to use its host (oldrustyjack.no-ip.info), I cannot connect. But server responds to ping.

Sorry for bad English.

Comment: Have you blocked ports, protocols or interfaces, for example with iptables or ufw? If not, maybe your operator blocks ports?

Comment: I connected internet provider support and they said they only block 25 port. But I cannot nor ping neither access apache on server now. =(